# opendir() a root directory

Tags: c, linux, directory

how can i open a directory that is is "/" using opendir()?

i have a c code that is working good, if i want to find a file inside a directory i just use the directory name (full path) and it find it for example /home/name and it finds it

But when i want to open a file that is find in "/" for example "sys" (just print in your terminal "cd /" and then ls and you'll find it there if you are using ubuntu, not sure for other distributions. and opendir() returns a null pointer. How can i be able to open root ("/") directory using opendir()?

so down here i posted the picture for better understanding. i run my script using "./get", the second parameter is the name of the directory that will be opened and the third parameter is the name of the file i want to find in that directory.

So if i want to find "catalog" file that is in /etc/xml my program works fine.

But if i want to find "gshadow" that is in /etc now it doesnt work, same for every directory in root

same happens if i do it in "/home", but if i run my program in "/home/vlad" works fine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fciYn.png)

```c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

void cautaInDirector(char *dirName, char *numefis) {

    DIR *dir;
    dir = opendir(dirName);
    struct dirent *dirEntry;
    struct stat inode;
    lstat(dirName, &inode);
    char name[1002];
    char namecale[1];
    if ((dir = opendir(dirName)) == NULL) {
        printf("NULL pointer\n");
        perror("opendir");
        printf("\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int n = 0;
    while ((dirEntry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        sprintf(name, "%s/%s", dirName, dirEntry->d_name);
        if (lstat(name, &inode) < 0) {
            perror("lstat");
            continue;
        }

        if (S_ISDIR(inode.st_mode)) {
            if ((strcmp(".", dirEntry->d_name) != 0)
                    && (strcmp("..", dirEntry->d_name) != 0)) {
                n++;
                cautaInDirector(name, numefis);
            }
            if (strcmp(numefis, dirEntry->d_name) == 0) {
                namecale[0] = n;
                // for(int i=1; i<strlen(dirEntry->d_name); i++){
                // namecale[i]=dirEntry->d_name[i-1];
                //  }
                strcpy(name, namecale);

                // printf("%s", dirEntry->d_name);
                for (int i = 0; i < strlen(name); i++)
                    printf("%c", name[i]);
                printf("\n");
                break;
            }
        }

        if (S_ISREG(inode.st_mode)) {
            n++;
            if (strcmp(numefis, dirEntry->d_name) == 0) {
                namecale[0] = n;
                //   for(int i=1; i<strlen(dirEntry->d_name); i++){
                //  namecale[i]=dirEntry->d_name[i-1];
                //  }
                strcpy(name, namecale);
                //sprintf(name,"%s/%s",dirName,namecale);
                //  printf("%s", dirEntry->d_name);
                for (int i = 0; i < strlen(name); i++)
                    printf("%c", name[i]);
                printf("\n");
                link(dirName, namecale);

            }
        }
    }
    //close(dir);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("Numar gresit de parametri");
        exit(1);
    }

    struct stat inode;
    lstat(argv[1], &inode);

    if (!S_ISDIR(inode.st_mode)) {
        printf("nu e director existent\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    cautaInDirector(argv[1], argv[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a [mre] that shows the problem. Check what error is recorded in `errno`, e.g. by calling `perror("opendir");` or similar.

Comment: sorry for not clarifying well enough, now i hope is ok

Comment: No, you still didn't produce the error returned by `opendir`. Please provide these. // Also, don't post text as (just) images. Please fix this.

Comment: i can provide code if you want, but the problem i dont think its the code. it work fine for any directory, so i can go in /home/vlad/dir1/dir2 and so on. the problem apears if i use it in /TheFirstDirectoryFromRoot

Comment: @vlad, Re "*i can provide code if you want*", Are you reading what we are writing??? While you need to provide the code too, that's it not what we asked for.

Comment: @ikegami yes ill modify the code now to return the specific error

Comment: "opendir: Too many open files"

Comment: This is `EMFILE`, which `opendir` returns when "the per-process limit on the number of open file descriptors has been reached." You appear to be opening lots of handles and not closing them. Please provide code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @ikegami code is up

Comment: You call `opendir` twice (leaking one handle) per call to the function. Then you recurse before closing the handle, so you could potentially open * a lot* of handles.

Comment: yes is true, i have deleted "dir = opendir(dirName);" but still the same error

Comment: Yes, but you still recurse before closing the handle.

Comment: I don't umderstand the purpose of the variable `namecale`. It is an array of 1 character. You copy an integer value `n` to it and want to use it with `strcpy` and `link`. Both is undefined behavior except when `namecale[0]` contains 0. The contents of your screenshot is basically text, so copy it to your question *as text* and format it as code blocks.

Comment: `printf("..."); exit(1);`  is always wrong.  If there is an error, then an error message should be written to stderr.  If there is no error, the exit status should be 0.  So you should either write `fprintf(stderr, "...."); exit(1);` or `printf("..."); exit(0);`  Exiting non-zero without writing anything to stderr is wrong.

Comment: The recursion by itself shouldn't be an issue unless the depth of directories is abnormally large.  It's the extra `opendir` at the beginning and the missing `closedir` that's the problem.

Answer (score 2):

`opendir` is returning `EMFILE`. According to the man page for `opendir` on my system, this is returned when "the per-process limit on the number of open file descriptors has been reached."

First of all, you call `opendir` twice per call to the function. The second call overwrites the result of the first, leaking one handle.

But that just speeds up the problem. It's not true cause. The real problem is that the function is recursive, and that you recurse before closing the handle. This potentially opens *a lot* of handles, especially if you start at the root directory.

You need to do something like:

1. Open the dir.
2. For each file in the dir,

   1. Stat the file.
   2. If it's a dir,

      1. Add it to a list to process.
   3. Else,

      1. Whatever.
3. Close the dir handle.
4. For each directory in the list to process,

   1. Call this function with the directory.

At least that's how it's done using `opendir`.  POSIX provides the easier to use [`nftw`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nftw.html), and the older, less flexible [`ftw`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ftw.html).

Comment: Or use POSIX's "new file tree walk" function, [`nftw()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nftw.html), or possibly the older and less flexible "(old) file tree walk", 
[`ftw()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ftw.html).